# Silverlight 5 clientaccesspolicy.xml

Tags: silverlight, iis-6, clientaccesspolicy.xml

I have a Silverlight 5 app that is making requests to a WCF data service over HTTPS on a separate domain (server) hosted via IIS 6 (at say mydomain.com/service.svc).

The silverlight app gets a SecurityException, which I assume is related to not finding a proper clientaccesspolicy.xml file. I have a clientaccesspolicy.xml file defined at mydomain.com's wwwroot folder that looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<access-policy>
  <cross-domain-access>
    <policy>
      <allow-from http-request-headers="*">
        <domain uri="*"/>
      </allow-from>
      <grant-to>
        <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>
      </grant-to>
    </policy>
  </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```

The weird part is that when looking at Fiddler traffic, there is never a request attempted for mydomain.com/clientaccesspolicy.xml.

The other thing is that the clientaccesspolicy.xml is served only over https (IIS setting on that server only allows ssl/tls connections), so could that be part of the problem?

Comment: both of them in the same (intranet/internet) zone?

Comment: @potatopeelings It doesn't work with or without fiddler, so I don't think it is a proxy issue

Answer (score 2):

You might try adding https:// explicitly in your allow-from:

```
<allow-from http-request-headers="*">
  <domain uri="http://*"/>
  <domain uri="https://*" />
</allow-from>
```

I assume when you try to hit the file directly you see it (IIS is actually serving it).

Comment: Yes! It seems that `uri="*"` is NOT a substitute for this. It seems that `*` only works from the same protocol. so if you are debugging on an `http://` URL locally and trying to access a remote service on `https://` 
this can be a great solution. of course depending upon the nature of what you are sending back and forth you may not want to allow http access.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
<allow-from http-request-headers="*">
  <domain uri="*"/>
  <domain uri="https://*" />
</allow-from>
```