# debugging resource strings are unavailable often the key and arguments silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, webclient, nullreferenceexception, xap

My client on production is facing this issue '**debugging resource strings are unavailable often the key and arguments**' in Silverlight. Bit, when I am trying to run code locally it is running successfully. But, on production, we are facing this issue. I am using WebClient class methods to load data from URI. Can anyone tell how to replicate this issue on local? Why it is happening on production site?

Answer (score 0):

"Debugging resource strings are unavailable. Often the key and arguments provide sufficient information to diagnose the problem. See `http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=...&Version=...&File=...&Key=...`" is a generic error message. In order to keep the Silverlight runtime small, some of the debugging-related strings were omitted, and the error message shows where to find more information (in case the link is still alive, given the fate of the Silverlight platform).

You should also investigate the exception type, and, if any, the inner exception. As you mentioned that you are using WebClient to access another URI, this could be a cross-domain policy issue. If the code is accessing resources on server with URI different the the one where the Silverlight application is published, you may need to upload special [clientaccesspolicy.xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13122875/silverlight-5-clientaccesspolicy-xml) on the server, allowing access to the resource.